# How to display an error message on a destroy action, since it redirects to index action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, error-handling, destroy

In a model I have:

```
before_destroy :ensure_not_referenced_by_any_shopping_cart_item
```

and

```
def ensure_not_referenced_by_any_shopping_cart_item
  unless shopping_cart_items.empty?
    errors.add(:base, "This item can't be deleted because it is present in a shopping cart")
    false
  end
end
```

When the item is present in a cart, it is not destroyed (which is good), and I see the error if I log it in the action..

```
def destroy
  @product = Beverage.find(params[:id])
  @product.destroy

  logger.debug "--- error: #{@product.errors.inspect}"

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to beverages_url }
    format.json { head :ok }
  end
end
```

..but the instance variable on which the error message was set is abandoned when the `redirect_to` happens, so the user never sees it.

How should the error message be persisted to the next action so it can be shown in its view?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using a flash message to relay the error information.

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to beverages_url, :alert => "An Error Occurred! #{@products.errors[:base].to_s}"
  format.json { head :ok }
end
```

Something to that effect. That is how I have handled similar issues in my own apps, but it depends on the detail of information you want to display to the user.

Comment: Thanks for including `#{@products.errors[:base].to_s}` in your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the error in the flash.  Something roughly like

```
def destroy
  @product = Beverage.find(params[:id])
  if @product.destroy
    message = "Product destroyed successfully"
  else
    message = "Product could not be destroyed"
  end


  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to beverages_url, :notice => message }
    format.json { head :ok }
  end
end
```

Note that you also need to be printing out messages in your `application.html.erb` file.

Comment: Thanks, @cailinanne, both your and @Justin Herrick's answers are correct, but I'm accepting his answer since his came in sooner. I still marked yours as "useful" though.. :) Also, thanks for the tip about `application.html.erb`!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with two messages, one with the status OK, and another with NO OK (*unprocessable_entity* for example, [here's more](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html)).

```
def destroy
  @product = Beverage.find(params[:id])


  respond_to do |format|
    if @product.destroy
     format.html { redirect_to beverages_url, notice: "Product destroyed successfully", status: :ok}
     format.json { head :ok, status: :ok}
    else
      format.html { redirect_to beverages_url, alert: "Product could not be destroyed", status: :unprocessable_entity}
      format.json {head :no_content, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 4, you can do like that

```
def destroy
  @product = Beverage.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @product.destroy
      format.html { redirect_to products_url, notice: 'Product was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :ok }
    else
      format.html { render :show }
      format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```